# In django, how do I return the other end of a many to many join?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have a table schema like this.

[image]

You're a user and you want to get the `list` of your other users (as `User` models). I've got a known `users.id` value.

The SQL for this query is relatively straightforward: join `users_B = entries_B.your_user` and `entries_B.other_user = users_B.id` where `entries_B.your_user = x`.

I can't figure out how to do this in django unless I post process the data (using `prefetch_related` counts as post processing) or generate a really weird query (something involving left joins and subqueries). Is there a way to get a list of `User`s back and have the generated SQL be straightforward and concise?

Here's the entry model:

```py
class Entry_B(models.Model):

    your_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="entries"
    )
    other_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="other_user_entries"
    )
    order = models.IntegerField()
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

The `User` model doesn't contain any fields relative to these relationships.

Comment: Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: Could you not use a `one-to-one` field for the `your_user` and a many field for the other_users?

Comment: @Cl0ud-l3ss I don't think so: there are multiple rows of `your_user` being the same.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated

Comment: In every 'enteries_B` table there's a possibility of multiple `your_user` enteries? Sorry I thought I understood. Definitely keeping an eye on this to see the solution.

Comment: I mean `entries_B` has 2 many-to-one relationships with with `user_B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
User.objects.filter(other_user_entries__your_user=myuser)
```

This will return the `User`s for which there is an `Entry_B` object where `your_user` is the given *`myuser`* object.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).